# Partial derivative -limit

Tags: limits, partial-derivative

I have problem because I must find a limit :

> $$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{h^5+2hk^2-hk^3}{h^4+2k^2}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

I think , that this will be zero.

Comment: limit does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist since $\displaystyle \lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{h^5+2hk^2-hk^3}{h^4+2k^2}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{h^5+2hk^2-hk^3}{(h^4+2k^2)\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$. 
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\lim_{k\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^5+2hk^2-hk^3}{(h^4+2k^2)\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^5}{h^4|h|}=1\,\text{or} -1.$$

Comment: please can you explain why?

Comment: It seems fine to me and, in any case, if you interchange the limits you will get 0, confirming your conclusion.

Comment: @Jon :I thought it was enough that is why I didnt write the limit for the other way around.